# What causes my problem when trying to create multiple tables in hook_schema?

Tags: database

I'm working on a module that has 2 tables and this is my code:

```
function gen_schema(){
$schema = array();

//table cv
$schema['cv'] = array(
        'description' => 'table contenant les cv.',
        'fields' => array(
                'cvid' => array(
                        'description' => 'clé primaire de la table cv.',
                        'type' => 'serial',
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                ),

                'uid' => array(
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique user ID.',
                        'default' => 0,
                ),
        ),

        'foreign keys' => array(
                'node_cv' => array(
                        'table' => 'node_revision',
                        'columns' => array('vid' => 'vid'),
                ),
        ),

        'primary key' => array('cvid'),
);

//table Information generale
$schema['information'] = array(
        'description' => 'table contenant les informations generales d\'un cv.',
        'fields' => array(
                'infoid' => array(
                        'description' => 'clé primaire de la table information.',
                        'type' => 'serial',
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                ),

                'cvid' => array(
                        'description' => 'clé primaire de la table cv.',
                        'type' => 'serial',
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                ),

                'uid' => array(
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'unsigned' => TRUE,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'description' => 'Primary Key: Unique user ID.',
                        'default' => 0,
                ),

                'nom' => array(
                        'description' => 'nom et prenom du proprietaire du cv.',
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'length' => 120,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '',
                ),

                'nationalite' => array(
                        'description' => 'nationalité du proprietaire du cv.',
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'length' => 120,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '',
                ),

                'profession' => array(
                        'description' => 'profession du proprietaire du cv.',
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'length' => 120,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '',
                ),

                /*'datenaiss' => array(
                        'description' => 'date de naissance du proprietaire du cv.',
                        'mysql_type' => 'datetime',
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '',
                ),*/

                'fonction' => array(
                        'description' => 'fonction du proprietaire du cv',
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'length' => 120,
                        'not null' => TRUE,
                        'default' => '',
                ),


        ),
        'foreign keys' => array(
                'node_cv' => array(
                        'table' => 'node_revision',
                        'columns' => array('cvid' => 'cvid'),
                ),
                'node_author' => array(
                        'table' => 'users',
                        'columns' => array('uid' => 'uid'),
                ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('infoid'),
);
```

But I'm getting this error **PDOEXCEPTION**, and only the `cv` table is created.

Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have two auto-incrementing fields on the second table. Only the primary key should be auto-incrementing:

```
'infoid' => array(
  'description' => 'clé primaire de la table information.',
  'type' => 'serial',
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
  'not null' => TRUE,
),
'cvid' => array(
  'description' => 'clé primaire de la table cv.',
  'type' => 'serial',
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
  'not null' => TRUE,
),
```

What you want for cvid is type 'int' not type 'serial'

```
'cvid' => array(
  'description' => 'clé primaire de la table cv.',
  'type' => 'int',
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
  'not null' => TRUE,
),
```

That should go through without a PDO exception.

Comment: @user59761 : if this answer really helped you, consider marking it as "accepted" (the green checkmark in front of this answer). For more details, have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers